# Facebook SDK for IOS can't go back to current view after login to Facebook but jump to app first view

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

My app has two views :

1. The main or first view that is shown when lunching app. While clicking on a vlidate button of this view, we go to second view.
2. The second view on witch there is a button "login to Facebook". While clicking on this button we can log in to facebook.

But after logged in to facebook, intead of returning back to current view (second view) it return to first view (main view)

Thank you!

Comment: Show your `if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {` code on the `UpdateView` if you are using the Facebook SDK.